# Check if if two line segments intersect in 3D space

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to find if two line segments intersects in 3D space. Both segments are given by points (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2). The following artcile describes how to do it in 2D space: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/ but I have no clue how to distinguish points orientation in 3D space (if they are clockwise or counter-clockwise). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2)` are two points, not 2 lines, and by removing this part of "text" from the question, does not help at all, which data do you have? the coefficient of the 2 lines? some points? what?

Comment: so you have 2 points for each line? PS: answer on the comments, not on the question

Comment: @Berto99 yes, two points for each line

Comment: so you want any intersection, of only intersections of the 2 segments made by connecting the 2 given points?

Comment: That site explains math: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/ Look at "The shortest line between two lines in 3D" as you likely want that if the two lines are closer than some tolerance at some point within segments then they intersect.

Comment: @Berto99 both segments are made by connecting those two points and I need two know if these segments intersect in some place.

Comment: Unless you have reasons to believe that the segments do intersect with significant probability, `return false` is not a bad option. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate direction vectors `d1` and `d2` for both segments  (`d1.x = x12-x11` and so on, where `x11` is starting point of the first segment, `x12` is ending point)

Calculate starting points difference (`b.x = x21 - x11` and so on)

Find

```
p = (d1 x d2) (vector product)
```

If p is zero vector, then lines are parallel.

If lines do intersect, `(b.dot.p)` should be = 0 (scalar product), else these lines are skew.

Intersection point:

```
ip = point11 + d1 * [ (b x d2).dot.p / (p.dot.p) ]
```

Note that value in `[]` should be in range `0..1`, otherwise lines intersect outside of segments.

Seems similar approach is described in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance)